# Incompatibility between cryptocode and autonum?

Tags: incompatibility, autonum

I would like to use the cryptocode and autonum packages. These packages seem to be incompatible. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}
 \procedure[]{Test}{Test}
\end{document}
```

When compiling this I get the following error, and loading the packages in the opposite order doesn't help either:

! LaTeX Error: Environment flalign* undefined.

It compiles as expected when commenting out the 3rd line.  Is this a known issue? I would like to use cleveref so using mathtools' \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs} (which provides a similar functionality) isn't a valid workaround, since it is known that showonlyrefs is incompatible with cleveref.

Comment: flalign is defined by amsmath, can't you just load that (or mathtools) (I don't understand your final comment about cleveref)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The OP seems to refer to the following statement from the `cleveref` manual: "Cleveref is  currently    incompatible    with    the mathtools package’s showonlyrefs option,  which automatically labels only those equations that are cross-referenced.  The autonum package provides a possible alternative, which implements similar features in a cleveref-compatible manner."

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, leandriis comment was correct. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @leandriis but surely that only means you can't use that option not that you can't load the package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `autonum`, star variants of the alignment environments are disallowed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{autonum}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\savedflalignstar\csname flalign*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\savedendflalignstar\csname endflalign*\endcsname
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\let\csname flalign*\endcsname\savedflalignstar
  \expandafter\let\csname endflalign*\endcsname\savedendflalignstar
}

\begin{document}

\procedure[]{Test}{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! @egreg: Do you think it is worth contacting the package maintainers? Do you think that there might be some undesired side-effects to your solution?

Comment: @OrSattath I think it's better to avoid `autonum`.

Comment: I like the feature which autonum provides. Would you mind expanding why is it better not to use it? Is it because this type of undesired effects that it has on other packages?

Comment: @OrSattath I'm not sure there are no side-effects: test it along with alignment environments. Why am I against it? No automation will substitute human judgment.

Comment: For future reference, I reported an issue to the maintainer via github: https://github.com/MagicMuscleMan/autonum/issues/6